# C# High accuracy Timing

Tags: c#

I am making a small typing test in C# in which the program asks you to type a word and then shows you your time.
I was using the c# timer class (drag and drop a timer from the toolbox), with a Tick time of 1ms, however it wasn't giving me accurate results, so I substituted it for a StopWatch , so now the timing is super accurate, but the problem is that it seems that you cannot assign event handlers to a StopWatch so although I can show the user his time when he FINISHES the word, I cannot actually show hum the time WHILE he is typing.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another Timer that fires events every 10th of a second or so and polls for the Stopwatch value. It won't be nearly as accurate as the Stopwatch since there will be a lag but humans can't really react to anything faster than a 10th of a second.

Answer (score 4):

Use a StopWatch to accurately measure time; and use a Timer to periodically fire a UI update, displaying the time measured by the StopWatch. For UI, you don't need 1 ms resolution (The screen update time is likely to be larger than 1 ms, and, the human eye won't be able to perceive updates that fast anyways).

Try having updates each 40 - 100 ms, I think that will be adequate.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `System.Timers.Stopwatch` class, and check if high resolution is available by checking the field `IsHighResolution` (`System.Timers.Stopwatch.IsHighResolution == true`).

Then, whenever you need something fired, fire it through another timer at the lowest interval possible, which checks the value of your `Stopwatch`. Though this won't be perfect (you don't even need close to perfect), it'll work.

Comment: You don't need an explicit comparison with true as the property is already a boolean ...